# Multipart file upload inside AWS Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, image, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I need to do a multipart file upload inside a Lambda function. Lambda is triggered by the S3 bucket on image upload. Need to get the uploaded image and then send it to another API service.Any suggestions?

Comment: A multi-part upload is traditionally used to upload _to_ Amazon S3. But you are saying you want to sent it to another API service, so where are you going to use the multi-part upload? Wouldn't you simply _download_ from S3, then send to the API service? How big are the objects in S3?

Comment: I'm doing it inside a lambda. So it's easy if I could do it without downloading it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
import FormData from "form-data";
import AWS from "aws-sdk";
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
    
const file = await S3.getObject({ Bucket, Key }).promise();
const formData = new FormData();
    
// since file.Body is returning a Buffer we need add filename
formData.append("image", file.Body, { filename: fileName);
const res = await axios.post('https://someUrl', formData, {
  headers: formData.getHeaders()
});
```